# PrimeNG - How to position a label above the input text field

Tags: angular, label, css-float, primeng, angular13

I'm using Angular 13 and PrimeNG 13.4.1. I would like to have a label to be directly above a text field, so I built:

```
<div class="ui-fluid" style="padding-top: 200px; padding-bottom: 200px;">
  <div class="p-field">
    <span class="p-float-label">
      <input type="text" formControlName="name" pInputText> 
      <label for="formLogoId">My Name</label>
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

However, when the field is rendered, the label appears superimposed over the text input.

[image]

What's the proper way to position the label above the text field?  I have this in my *angular.json* file, for what it's worth.

```
"styles": [
  "node_modules/primeng/resources/themes/nova/theme.css",
  "node_modules/primeng/resources/primeng.min.css",
  "node_modules/primeicons/primeicons.css"
],
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the attached HTML, you are applying [Float Label](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/floatlabel).

If you want the label to be positioned at the top of input field, you can refer to [InputText Demo (the Invalid section part)](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/inputtext).

> HTML

```
<div class="p-field">
    <label for="formLogoId">My Name</label>
    <input type="text" formControlName="name" pInputText />
</div>
```

> CSS

```
.p-field > * {
  display: block;
}
```

The CSS part is crucial, which all the elements under the element with the `p-field` class will be applied with style: `display: block`.

Without it, the `<label>` element will be at the left and the `<input>` element at the right (position).

[Sample StackBlitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-oeoszf?file=src/app/app.component.html)

> Output

[image]

---

You may consider for [PrimeFlex](https://primefaces.org/primeflex/), which is a CSS library for Prime UI.

1. Install primeflex library.

```
npm install primeflex
```

2. Import CSS in angular.json or root stylesheet.

```
"node_modules/primeflex/primeflex.css"
```

3. Apply PrimeFlex styling.

```
<div class="field">
    <label for="formLogoId">My Name</label>
    <input type="text" formControlName="name" pInputText class="w-full" />
</div>
```

Refer: [FormLayout](https://primefaces.org/primeflex/formlayout)

[Sample StackBlitz Demo (PrimeFlex)](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-tq8ayu?file=src/app/app.component.html)

Comment: Thanks for this code and demo.  Do you know if primeNg have any styles that do this out of the box?  I'm happy to define the CSS the way you have it here, but if primeNg already provides styles that do what I want, I'd rather use those.

Comment: Hi, I updated my answer. You may consider PrimeFlex library.